# Snowflake SQL Sum from another table based on matching values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I could really use some help here here. Know how to do this with Excel SUMIFS, but Table 1 is way too big for Excel + my data is already in Snowflake SQL.  I'd like to determine the Sales in Table 2 when it matches Table 1 (on Store, Product, and Date is within Start & End Date)  I will use this to determine which Price Promotions drove the most Sales over a Baseline Period.  Thank you!!

### Table1

| Store | Date | Product | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1-2021 | A | 12 |
| 1 | 1-1-2021 | B | 20 |
| 1 | 1-6-2021 | A | 14 |
| 1 | 1-6-2021 | B | 9 |
| 2 | 1-1-2021 | A | 29 |
| 2 | 1-1-2021 | B | 17 |
| 2 | 1-6-2021 | A | 5 |
| 2 | 1-6-2021 | B | 21 |

### Table 2

| Store | Start Date | End Date | Campaign | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1-2021 | 1-3-2021 | Spend $100 then Save $10 | A |
| 2 | 1-2-2021 | 1-5-2021 | 15% Off | B |

Comment: What is your expected output? the SUM of `Sales` in each `Campaign` for each (store-product)? Please include your `SUMIFS` statement, and the SQL query you have tried.

Comment: Yes, I hope to obtain the Sales for each Campaign.  Not even sure where to start on Snowflake SQL query.  If I was doing in Excel with SUMIFS, it would be something like =SUMIFS(Table1.Sales.Column, Table1.Store.Column=Table2.Store.Value, Table1.Product.Column=Table2.Product.Value, Table1.Date.Column >= Table2.Start_Date.Value, Table1.Date.Column <= Table2.End_Date.Value)

Comment: Can you give us a explicit expected output for this input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking for a `join` and aggregation?

```
select t2.store, t2.start_date, t2.end_date, t2.product,
       sum(t1.sales)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.store = t2.store and
        t1.product = t2.product and
        t1.date >= t2.start_date and
        t1.date <= t2.end_date
group by t2.store, t2.start_date, t2.end_date, t2.product;
```